# Application cannot connect to dockerized Rabbitmq service

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq

I am testing my Rabbitmq's tutorial project.

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    factory.setPort(5672);
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

the last line of the code above eventually gives a timeout exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:646)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:678)
```

I started my dockerized rabbitmq service with this command

`docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`

and with `docker ps` I have this

```
b36bd68466db        rabbitmq:3-management    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   49 seconds ago      Up 49 seconds       4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   rabbitmq
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Are you able to browse to the management UI at http://localhost:15672?

Comment: yes! @ThomasPortwood   but pinging from terminal doesnt work.

Comment: Can you clarify the setup of your tutorial project? Just want to make sure whether it's dockerized itself or not.

Comment: This is not worthy of a full post, but please have a look at your firewall settings too. System Preferences, Security & Privacy, Firewall, Firewall Options. Blocking all incoming connections with the firewall could be the reason your ping fails. I'm not 100% sure it is the cause of your connection timeout though.

Comment: Can you do `telnet localhost 5672`?

Comment: @AliTou yes   telnet localhost 5672
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.